# include PHPWhoIs by default for all scripts

Tags: php, configuration, include-path

So I have PHPWhoIs located in `plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2` of the root of my server.

I'm able to use the `Whois()` class in php scripts by including it like:

```
include_once('../../../plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2/whois.main.php');

$whois = new Whois();
```

But I'm trying to make my server include this file by default.  I've tried adding this to my php.ini

```
include_path=".:/plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2/whois.main.php"
```

And confirmed it took with `var_dump(ini_get('include_path'));`, but then it says the class `Whois()` doesn't exist.

I also notice I'm overwriting the default `include_path`.

How can I add this path to be included so it will work by default in any script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include path is used to tell PHP where to look when you use an include in your code, so it's a list of directories... it doesn't automatically do the includes for you

So with

```
include_path=".:/plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2
```

in your php.ini, then

```
include "whois.main.php"
```

will successfully find the file to include

You might look at the [auto_prepend_file](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) ini setting though to include a specific php file before the main body of your script

Comment: How would I use auto_prepend_file?

Comment: The idea is to not have to include the file each time I want to use it for each site.

Comment: @stevether - the __auto__ part of auto_prepend_file means automatic, ie you don't have to manually include each time. And you use it by setting auto_prepend_file="/plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2/whois.main.php" in your php.ini, then just instantiate the class in your scripts

Answer (score 1):

**The real issue here is that you don't want to write the path to include the file.**  Use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead.

If you still need to set up a default include path, I recommend that you simply echo the current include paths in a script and then use that in `php.ini`, adding your `plugins` directory or whatever the base include path is.  Using this in conjunction with an autoloader is highly effective.

Then inside of your include path, make `setup.php` and use it to set up your autoloader.  Now on any of your pages, your include is simply `require 'setup.php';`.

Comment: But don't I have to use this in each file that I would want to use this script with?

Comment: @stevether I updated my question.  Hope it helps you understand.

Answer (score 0):

The "include_path" parameter you're altering is the wrong one, though the name does suggest that it's relevant. It's in fact used to set the default *directory* which include files are looked for in - many people prefer their includes to be out of their usual webspace to prevent them being run out of context, among other reasons.

I believe the parameter you would need to set would be auto_prepend_file. Set this to the relevant file and it should load as if included on every script.